# Cache uitableview data in memory

Tags: iphone, ios, json, caching

I get an array (containing text) called `titleArray` from json which I populate a uitableview with. I would like to cache it in memory so that data for the screen loads once, it will not need to load again per session. I've never done this..

basically I have 2 methods:

`- (void)requestFinishedWithResult:(NSDictionary*)result`

`- (void)requestFailed` 
depending on if I get anything from the server.

Somewhere in the `- (void)requestFinishedWithResult:(NSDictionary*)result` I'm thinking I need an additional array to store the `titleArray` data in...and then do something like this: ??

```
 -(void)requestFailed
{
    if (titleArray != nil) 
    {
        storeArray = titleArray;
    }
}
```

or something like that? but I really don't know how it should work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what kind of persistance you want. You can store it on the disk and then load it and have a mechanism to update that cached data. Or, you can just store on an ivar and retain it's value, this way you will have the data for the duration of the application.

Comment: I would like to store it in an ivar...I just don't know what that would look like. The code above is my sad attempt. Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: When the requested fail, there isn't much you can do besides warning the user. When the request succeeds you can store your NSDictionary (that comes from the method) in your own dictionary: `self.myDictionary = result;`